# Checkout only updated files from remote repository

Tags: git, svn

Suppose somebody changed the remote repository how do I know what files are modified. Need help for both git and svn.

Note:I don't want to checkout the remote repository.

Comment: When you use Git you don't checkout files, you checkout entire branches.  Can you elaborate on your problem?

Comment: In git, run `fetch`, not `pull`, then review the changes.

Comment: I just want to know the file names which have been changed without any change to my local repository given that somebody else has changed the remote repository

Comment: @choroba I also want to know the modified file names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you update Subversion working copy, it downloads only changed items. It does not re-download everything again.

If you want to check what items will be updated when you next run `svn update`, run `svn status -u` command.  According to [the second example](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html#idp21230496) in the red book:

> If you want to find out what files in your working copy are out of date, pass the `--show-updates` (`-u`) option...

This will give output like:

```
$ svn status -u wc
 M            965    wc/bar.c
        *     965    wc/foo.c
A  +          965    wc/qax.c
Status against revision:    981
```

Here, only foo.c is out of date (the asterisk indicates that the repository version is more recent than your working copy).

Answer (score 1):

Don't know for svn, but for git maybe this is what you're looking for

```
git fetch
git diff origin/master --name-only
```

Comment: For git yes this is what I am looking for.